# Populate email send date and time from another email in template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

Essentially, I'm trying to get the send date and time for when a previous email was sent to include in a new email - for a journey.

I know `%%=GetSendTime()=%%` can get it for that email, but is there a way with the email ID of another email to get when that was sent to the individual subscriber?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to do a [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) or [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) to a data extension where that email ID and send time is stored. Possibly a [SendLog](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333925&type=1&mode=1) if had that set up.

Alternatively, you can also set up an automation to query the [_Sent data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) to write to a data extension so that you can retrieve using the above lookup methods.

[GetSendTime and Now(1)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/GetSendTime.htm) only applies to the current send and not the send of a different email job.